# Join two Array with same value and add this in one JSON using Javascript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two JSON objects with the same structure/value and I want to concat them together using Javascript.

My first array looks like this:

```js
[{
        "name": "Spain",
        "year": [
            "2010"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Brazil",
        "year": [
            "1994",
            "1970",
            "1962",
            "2002",
            "1958"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Germany",
        "year": [
            "2014",
            "1990",
            "1974",
            "1954"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Italy",
        "year": [
            "2006",
            "1982",
            "1938",
            "1934"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "France",
        "year": [
            "2018",
            "1998"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Argentina",
        "year": [
            "1986",
            "1978"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Uruguay",
        "year": [
            "1930",
            "1950"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "England",
        "year": [
            "1966"
        ]
    }
]
```

My second array:

```js
[{
        "name": "Spain",
        "anzahl": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Brazil",
        "anzahl": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "Germany",
        "anzahl": 4
    },
    {
        "name": "Italy",
        "anzahl": 4
    },
    {
        "name": "France",
        "anzahl": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Argentina",
        "anzahl": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Uruguay",
        "anzahl": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "England",
        "anzahl": 1
    }
]
```

I am looking for a solution to merge all the same keys and add the values of the merged keys together to get something looking like this:

```js
[{
        "name": "Spain",
        "year": [
            "2010"
        ]
        "anzahl": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Brazil",
        "year": [
            "1994",
            "1970",
            "1962",
            "2002",
            "1958"
        ]
        "anzahl": 5
    },
    .....
]
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map through the first array and use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to assign the properties from the item with the same `name` property in the second array (with [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) to the current item:

```js
const arr1=[{name:"Spain",year:["2010"]},{name:"Brazil",year:["1994","1970","1962","2002","1958"]},{name:"Germany",year:["2014","1990","1974","1954"]},{name:"Italy",year:["2006","1982","1938","1934"]},{name:"France",year:["2018","1998"]},{name:"Argentina",year:["1986","1978"]},{name:"Uruguay",year:["1930","1950"]},{name:"England",year:["1966"]}],arr2=[{name:"Spain",anzahl:1},{name:"Brazil",anzahl:5},{name:"Germany",anzahl:4},{name:"Italy",anzahl:4},{name:"France",anzahl:2},{name:"Argentina",anzahl:2},{name:"Uruguay",anzahl:2},{name:"England",anzahl:1}]

const result = arr1.map(e => Object.assign(e, arr2.find(f => f.name == e.name)))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution to work with any number of dynamic keys:

[Solution Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2n5xf47d/)

```
const json1 = [{
    name: "test1",
    city: [
    ]
}, {
    name: "test2",
    city: [
    ]
}];
const json2 = [{
    age: "19",
    address:"cb usa"
}, {
    age: "20"
}];
let t = Object.assign({}, json1);
for(let i=0;i< json1.length;i++) {
     let l = Object.keys(json2[i]);
     for(let j=0;j< l.length;j++) {
           t[i][l[j]] =json2[i][l[j]] ;
    }   
}
console.log(t);
```